# getting json key values pairs from array

Tags: android

```
{"work":[{"position":{},"employer":{},"start_date":"2014-01-11","location":{}},{}}],"hometown":{""},"location":{},"locale":"en_GB","link":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/profile.php?id=100002375124798","education":[],"updated_time":"2014-01-20T17:28:10+0000","id":"100002375124798","first_name":"Faizan","timezone":5,"quotes":"The one who loves u is going to hurt from you bcz its a life yahan sub ahsa he hota ha.........","verified":true,"name":"Faizan Khan","last_name":"Khan","gender":"male"}
```

this is my json how can i get first_name, last_name, gender from this, i also get json by creatin jsonobject but i cant get above keyvalue pairs?

Comment: Your json is not validating in jsonlint

Comment: Yes, your json is not correct format, put the string in jsonviewer like http://json.parser.online.fr/ and check it.

Comment: @user3423119 what you want to do with this json????

Comment: i want to login from facebook in my app, after login i will get response just like above format of json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON has an invalid format. If you have the correct JSON, you can do something like this:

```
String myJSON = ...
//Here we construct a JSONObject, because it makes handling JSON formatted Strings much 
//easier than having them in plain String format
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
String first_name = jObj.getString(first_name);
```

Comment: It should through JsonException. Because the json is not in proper format

Comment: It will throw a JSONException indeed. That's why I said do it if you have the correct JSON.

Comment: The JSON you provided in your initial question is not verified as valid JSON by jsonlint.com . I do not know what you did but you did not verify the JSON you posted in your question, because that one is invalid.

Comment: @schubakah I have android application , want to add log in by facebook in my android application. I get the JSON response after facebook log in,but json response is not valid.